# Creating a SwiftUI Button using personal image

Tags: image, button, swiftui

I am having an issues in swiftui when creating a button or navigationlink using an image as the button.  Once I get the code setup the image is blue.

```
NavigationView {
               VStack {
                   Text("Hello World")
                   NavigationLink(destination: areaexample()) {
                       Image("testpic")
                       .resizable()
                       .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                       .cornerRadius(50)
               }
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some components in iOS automatically apply a caller called `tint`. If you need to override this behavior, Set the rendering mode of the image to `.renderingMode(.original)`

```
Image("testpic").renderingMode(.original)
```